# Persist/Restore Scala Instance (to/from File)

Tags: scala, serialization, marshalling

### What is the simplest way to save/restore an instance in Scala to/from a File?

Now that scala.util.Marshal has been removed and the innovative Pickling library appears unsupported (requires the use of Scala 2.10.4).

Example:

```
val myObj = SortedSet(20, 10, 30)
SomeUtil.saveToFile(myObj)

//...later:
val restored: SortedSet[Int] = SomeUtil.restoreFromFile(filename)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22504804/651140 and [SerializationUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works with Scala 2.11.1, but is much more messy than what I had expected from a modern class library:

### saveToFile

```
def saveToFile (obj: Object, filename: String) = {
  val out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
  try {
    out.write(Serializer.serialize(obj))
  }
  finally {
    out.close();
  }
}
```

### restoreFromFile

```
def restoreFromFile[T] (filename: String): Option[T] = {
  try {
    val file = new FileInputStream(filename)
    val in = Stream.continually(file.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
    Some(Serializer.deserialize(in).get)
  }
  catch {
    case _: Exception => None
  }
}
```

### object Serializer {

```
  def serialize[T] (obj: T): Array[Byte] = { // use instead of Marshal.dump in Scala 2.11
    val byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream)
    out.writeObject(obj)
    out.close()
    byteStream.toByteArray
  }

  def deserialize[T] (data: Array[Byte]): Try[T] = { // use instead of Marshal.load in Scala 2.11
    if (data == null)
      Failure(new NullPointerException())
    else {
      val in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
      try {
        Success(in.readObject.asInstanceOf[T])
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => Failure(e)
      }
      finally {
        in.close()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way is to use the Java classes: ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Mark your custom class with @SerialVersionUID:

```
@SerialVersionUID(1L)
class MyClass extends Serializable {...}
```

### Save

```
val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filename)))
out.writeObject(this)
out.close
```

### Restore

```
val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)))
val myInstance = in.readObject().asInstanceOf[MyClass]
in.close
```